# AWS EMR InvalidAuxServiceException: The auxService:mapreduce_shuffle does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-emr

I am launching an EMR cluster at run time based on an User Event and once the job is done the cluster will be terminated.

How ever when i the cluster is launched and the tasks are getting executed i am getting the Error:

I read some posts where it is being suggested that we need to  update yarn-site.xml in namenode and datanodes and restart the yarn instance.

Not sure how to configure this during the launch of the cluster itself.

```html
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidAuxServiceException: The auxService:mapreduce_shuffle does not exist
```

```
Container launch failed for container_1523533251407_0001_01_000002 : org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidAuxServiceException: The auxService:mapreduce_shuffle does not exist
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.instantiateException(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:168)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.deSerialize(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:106)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$Container.launch(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:155)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$EventProcessor.run(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:390)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Thanks

Answer:

Here is what i have added in my code to resolve the Issue:

```
Map<String,String> yarnProperties = new HashMap<String,String>();
        yarnProperties.put("yarn.nodemanager.aux-services","mapreduce_shuffle");
        yarnProperties.put("yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class","org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler");

        Configuration yarnConfig = new Configuration()
                .withClassification("yarn-env")
                .withProperties(yarnProperties);
RunJobFlowRequest request = new RunJobFlowRequest()
            .withConfigurations(yarnConfig)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were setting some other properties in the yarn-site.xml .

In case you are trying to create using AWS CLI, you can use

> --configurations  'json file with the config'

Else if you are trying to create through java , for example

```
Application hive = new Application().withName("Hive");

Map<String,String> hiveProperties = new HashMap<String,String>();
    hiveProperties.put("hive.join.emit.interval","1000");
    hiveProperties.put("hive.merge.mapfiles","true");

Configuration myHiveConfig = new Configuration()
    .withClassification("hive-site")
    .withProperties(hiveProperties);
```

Then you can refer as

```
RunJobFlowRequest request = new RunJobFlowRequest()
    .withName("Create cluster with ReleaseLabel")
    .withReleaseLabel("emr-5.13.0")
    .withApplications(hive)
    .withConfigurations(myHiveConfig)
```

For the other problem :-

You need to add this 2 properties in the above way and then create the cluster:-

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```